# Custom Error Message Text with Jquery Validate Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Need to copy the Custom error message text from a span where text is coming from CMS. It is basically a need to show a custom localized error message.

Code works when you submit the form but as soon as you click outside, the default message replace the custom one.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nV5u/16/

HTML

```
<form name="form-core" id="form-core" method="post" action="" role="search"  novalidate="novalidate">
      <label for="keywords">Hello</label>
      <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="required" />
      <span class="error-message-required">Ce champ est obligatoire</span>
      <input type="submit" /><input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Reset" />         
</form>
```

JS

```
 $('#form-core').validate({
            debug: false,
            onfocusout: function (element) { jQuery(element).valid() },
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                jQuery('div[for=' + error.attr('for') + ']').remove();
                    error.text($(element).next('.error-message-required').text());
                    error.insertBefore(element);
                }                
        });
```

Comment: Try remove these lines from JS

    jQuery(element).valid()

Comment: tried that but then when you enter a character and remove it again. Dafult error message text again comes into picture

Comment: Please remove error message from the model property.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal, there is nothing wrong with `jQuery(element).valid()` inside his `onfocusout` callback function.  He's merely triggering instant validation on focus out before the submit button activates it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681406/jquery-validate-custom-messages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not working the way you expect because the `errorPlacement` callback function is not fired on every error.  It's only fired on the first occurrence of the error and then the plugin automatically shows/hides the new error element that *it* created by itself.

**1)**  I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be.  Simply specify your custom error message inside the `.validate()` initialization function.  Remove the `<span></span>` from your HTML/CMS and let the plugin handle this the way it was designed.

```
messages: {
    keyword: {
        required: "Ce champ est obligatoire"
    }
}
```

**2)**  Again, let the plugin do its job. Change your `errorPlacement` callback function to this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertBefore(element);
}
```

**3)**  Change your reset button to `type="reset"`, so that it's not submitting the form:

```
<input class="cancel" type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wQaYw/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form-core').validate({
        messages: {
            keyword: {
                required: "Ce champ est obligatoire"
            }
        },
        onfocusout: function (element) {
            jQuery(element).valid()
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT**:

If, for whatever reason, you cannot remove the `span` from your CMS and declare the custom messages inside of `.validate()`, you have another option.

Use the [built-in `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) to dynamically alter the default messages for every `input[type="text"]`, with a `required` rule, on the entire form as follows.  (**However**, with this method, you **must** supply a custom message for each of these elements as this will over-ride all of them.)

```
$('#form-core input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        messages: {
            required: $(this).next('.error-message-required').text()
        }
    });
});
```

after this...

```
$('#form-core').validate({
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        jQuery(element).valid()
    },
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vzdz/**

Comment: thanks a ton @Sparky ! built-in rules options is looking like a perfect fill for my problem. What i also tried is to capture the validate().settings object and extend the messages object on the fly. Will provid more updates after finishing the project tasks.