# jQuery Validate custom messages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, custom-data-attribute

I have an input that I want to display a custom error message on when the user doesn't fill it out.

```
    <input type="text" class="foo" value="" data-prop="foo" data-rules="{ required: true }"></input>
```

How do I add a custom error message to this specific input?

Comment: Would something similar to what soupenvy suggests here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777634/jquery-validation-plugin-custom-message?rq=1 solve your issue?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Most-likely no. I'd prefer to avoid jQuery to override the message on just one. Isn't there a way to set this with an attribute?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use:

```
data-msg-required="Please enter something here!"
```

Here's a demo HTML code: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/custom-messages-data-demo.html

JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/VuPPy/48/

Comment: you made my life easy

Comment: @San: glad it was of help... :-)

Comment: I have one more small question I am using data-rule-range="[14,30]" for range in my html5 form. I am using multistep form plugin of jquery stepy which uses jquery validate. How can i use the field from using only alphabets. I can use something like data-regex???

Comment: @San... kindly ask a new question. This looks like a better way of handling it instead of here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery-validate.js library (https://jqueryvalidation.org/), you can also use js to do this job.

See my html part:

```
<input type="text" id="TBBusquedaDescripcionCategoriaEd" name="TBBusquedaDescripcionCategoriaEd" maxlength="300" class="form-control" required>
```

Then in js:

```
var validator = $("#formName").validate({
        rules: {
            TBBusquedaDescripcionCategoriaEd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
        messages: {
            TBBusquedaDescripcionCategoriaEd: {
                required: "Mandatory field custom msg",
                minlength: "Minleght custom msg"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {...});
```